# check element of one array in another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have 3 arrays, I want to check if any element of subarray in mainArray is exist - then it should return true.

I have tried this, but it is returning true only if mainArray containing all the item of sub array.

MY js:

```
var sub1 = ["0", "10"];
var sub2 = ["18", "3", "13", "4"];
var mainArr = ["0", "1", "5", "8", "9", "10"];
if (containsChk(sub1, mainArr)) {
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}

function containsChk(sub, main) {
    for (var i = 0, len = sub.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ($.inArray(sub[i], main) == -1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/gd9ftbc4/1/)

Comment: Turn it around, return true if it IS in array and return false after the for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just use `array.indexOf()` (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp).

```
for (var i = 0; i < sub1.length; i++)
   if (mainArray.indexOf(sub1[i]) != -1)
      return true;
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  var sub1 = ["0", "10"];
var sub2 = ["18", "3", "13", "4"];
var mainArr = ["0", "1", "5", "8", "9", "10"];
if (containsChk(sub1, sub2, mainArr)) {
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}


function containsChk(sub, sub2, main) {
    var isIn = false;
    for (var i = 0, len = sub.length; i < len; i++) {
        if ($.inArray(sub[i], main) != -1) {
            isIn = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isIn) {
        for (var i = 0, len = sub2.length; i < len; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(sub2[i], main) != -1) {
                 isIn = true;
                 break;
            }
        }
    }


    return isIn;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Bala_chandran/gd9ftbc4/4/)

Comment: it is too complicated. check below answer.